# Wordpress php get_post_meta for post template

Tags: php, wordpress, meta, posts

I am using this little technique outlined here :

https://mekshq.com/include-javascriptonly-on-specific-wordpress-page-templates/

to limit the quantity of scripts etc. which load up on different pages on my site, by using the code:

```
$template_name = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
if($template_name == 'my-custom-template.php'){ 
    //load my scripts 
}
```

But I would like to use the same technique for POST templates, however '_wp_page_template' doesn't seem to recognize post templates, just page templates.

Is there some way I can change this to query if it is a post template instead? If not can I at least query if it is a post rather than a page, irrespective of template? That would probably be good enough, although querying the template would be preferable as it would give me more flexibility going forward.

I tried to look it up but sry, I am really not very strong in .php and most of the imfo I found is too complicated for me to rly follow.... like here there is a lot of info but it's like a week long lesson for me :/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to add that JS files only on template ?

Comment: for posts listing page please check with this : `if(is_archive('post_type_name') )` and if you want to check for detail page then this : `if(is_single('post_type_name') )`

Comment: Yeah, just to load up the JS i need for each page rather than extra, same for css as I want to format some common elements differently. And sry raju, dont follow you at all, as I said I am not too strong in php, and I have no idea how to fit in what you said with the get_post_meta part.